# Reading returned data from Stripe OAuth Redirect-URI (Stripe OAuth, Firebase back-end, React front-end)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, oauth, stripe-payments, uri

I am completely stuck trying to figure out how to allow users to sign up a "Connected Account" via Stripe OAuth steps for my website. (I'm building a marketplace website with React front-end, Firebase back-end, and Stripe to handle payments).

Some guides I have been trying to use to help guide me are as follows:

(1) https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide : I am stuck on this guide at step 2.2. However this guide is not as helpful since I am using Firebase as my backend. 
(2) https://medium.com/@c.nwaugha/integrate-stripe-payment-with-firebase-cloud-functions-part-2-e381babd39bc : I am stuck on this guide at around 1/3rd up the page (see yellow text of image below)
[image]

Unfortunately I'm not sure what my Stripe Redirect URI should be.  I currently have it set to something similiar to "https:MyWebsiteName.com/oauth_redirect" on my Stripe settings, however this link doesn't have a React front-end yet and am not sure what code it should contain.

Simply put, how can I continue the OAuth setup process and pull the data from a returned URL. Any clarity is greatly appreciated. (PS: I did look into "Regex" as the guide suggests, but am unable to find anything that appears to be useful for this case).

**UPDATE and PARSING URL SOLUTION**
Thanks to hmunoz's advice, I was able to parse through the returned URL and capture the stripe OAuth Authorization Code in a string. (Please see the code below).

This is returned when this page "https://.../oauth_return" URI is reached after the user finishes the OAuth forms on stripe.

```
import React from 'react';
import queryString from 'query-string'; //this is a 3rd party library that is used to parse through the Redirect URL returned from Stripe.


const oauth_redirect  = () => {

    //Parsing over URL
    const value=queryString.parse(window.location.search);

    //Retrieves the "code" value.
    const code=value.code;
    console.log('code:', code)

    //Retrieves the "state" value.
    const state=value.state;
    console.log('state:', state)

... //(I'm not sure how to pass these strings into a Firebase HTTP function).
}

export default (oauth_redirect)
```

**CURRENT PROBLEM; BUILDING FIREBASE HTTP FUNCTION USING JAVASCRIPT**
I am trying to build a Firebase HTTP function that uses the POST method, to return this Authorization Code. I have a function inside "index.js" of the functions/src directory of this react website. Unfortunately all of the guides on this subject have the firebase function is .typescript and I am using .javascript.  Any clarity on how build this HTTP function in .javascript would be greatly appreciated!!!

Please note:  I clarified the question a bit in the following post :[Returning Authorization Code to Stripe using Firebase HTTP Function (Firebase, Stripe OAuth, React (JSX) frontend)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509180/returning-authorization-code-to-stripe-using-firebase-http-function-firebase-s)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `redirect_uri` in this case is the final page that you want your user to land on, once they have authenticated via Stripe.

This would have to be a web page of yours, say https://your-website.com/oauth-complete

Once on this page, your React code needs to grab the URL parameter like `code: ac_123` which is the authorization code, and call a Firebase function with that authorization code.

Your Firebase function will complete the OAuth connection to this Connect account by consuming the OAuth token.

These two steps are described here: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-standard-accounts#redirected

Comment: Thanks hmunoz.  I'll take this info and try to see if I can parse the Authorization Code from the URL and pass it along to a Firebase Function as you suggest.

Comment: I was able to get the URL parsed and now have the authorization code; however I haven't been able to find a tutorial to help walk through how to build the Firebase HTTP function that returns this authorization code to stripe (in .javascript).  Any clarity on this particular issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Firebase integrations but I'm guessing it typically looks like your integration calling a Firebase cloud function with the authorization code. In your cloud function, you use the authorization code to connect that Stripe account to your Platform. And you store the Stripe account ID you get from that response in a database like Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I've arrived too late. You can start simple uncommeting the example from the index.js in /functions.

You can test running firebase emulators:start from your terminal.

It might start in the localhost:5001/project-name/zone/newFunction

```
exports.newFunction = functions.https.onRequest( (req, res) => {
 // your logic code here
}
```